# radare2 redirect input output to another terminal while debugging

Tags: macos, debugging, terminal, disassembly

I can't find out how to get input to, or output from a command line application while debugging with radare2. Is there any way to redirect this to another terminal.

I'm using macos El Capitan.

Answer (score 0):

You should create `rarun2` profile and use it to define `stdio` as your other terminal. That's way you can debug an application on one terminal whereas the input and output would be in the second terminal.

See my answer in [Debugging with radare2 using two terminals](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/16430/18698).